# Adding a JavaScript Module to the homepage

Tags: magento2, module, javascript

I've followed the DevDoc on [How to Add a JavaScript Module (Magento 2.2)](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-javascript-module/) and it works fine. However, I can't get it to work on my Magento site homepage. I added

> /app/code/Learning/Js/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

with the same code as the `sample catalog_product_view.xml` and I can see that the relevant code appears in my homepage source viewed from a browser. However, the JavaScript fails to run.

> catalog_product_view.xml / cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Learning_Js::hello.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    </page>
```

You can view the test site homepage at http://magento.onlinekit.co.uk/ and the working Module at http://magento.onlinekit.co.uk/surridge-adult-century-3-4-sleeve-cricket-shirt (it displays a 'Hello World' alert).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this script and remove or disabled from homepage: `<script type="text/x-magento-init" src="js/hello-world.js"></script>`

Comment: That piece of code was a remnant from an earlier attempt to use custom js; I thought I'd removed it from my theme. The custom module is now working. Thanks Kunj.

Comment: Welcome, it was stopping to `main.js` to execute other `text/x-magento-init` and `data-mage-init` because of no JSON data in that `<script type="text/x-magento-init" src="js/hello-world.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add **js** directly in XML, you will directly redirect you to the infinite errors !

The best way to add js in Theme is within `requirejs`

Here is how to add it:

Supposing that your js file is: `myfile.js`

**app/design/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert('hello myscript');
           //put all your myfile js code here
       }
});
```

**app/design/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Please re-read my original question. I stated that I'm using a Magento DevDoc example, which uses RequireJs. All I'm asking is why it doesn't work on the homepage, but works on a product catalog page.